# Magento: how to override getOrder getGrandTotal for purpose of changing amount when passing the value to payment modules

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to change the order grand total programmatically for purpose of allowing users to pay portion of the payment.  I tried editing core file Mage_Payment_Model_Info   method getMethodInstance

```
if (method_exists($instance,"getOrder")){
    $order = $instance->getOrder(); 
}else{

        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        $order->loadByIncrementId($session->getLastRealOrderId());

}
$total=$order->getGrandTotal()/2;
$order->setGrandTotal($total);
```

I know this is not the best way, but was experimenting to find the best way . How to achieve this? I plan to put the changed in a custom module. so not going to keep changes in core files. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar recently and there were some big problems, but first the good news.

- The amount charged is based on invoices, invoice for the portion and the order's paid amount will increase appropriately.
- An order may have many invoices.
- You don't need to alter the grand total. Leave that intact as a record of what they need to pay.

However,

- The *order items* each need to be marked as invoiced. When an order is half paid then you must work out which items are accounted for intelligently. If an order has one $10 item and one $100 item which are paid by the first $20?
- An order cannot be overpaid. Thanks to a false assumption the difference between amount owed and amount paid (the "due") will not show negative numbers, this is a fallacy and makes it really hard to pay two pending orders at once.

One way that I didn't think of in time would be to have credit accounts for each customer. When a payment is less than the entire order add it to the account instead and leave the order unpaid for now. Allow arbitrary (pre)payments to the account. Once the account is great enough use it to pay the order, you might want to make a payment module for this bit.
Or it could work in reverse, pay all orders immediately and leave a negative balance in the credit account to be paid at a later date. I suspect this would be the least painful way of all.

Comment: thanks a lot for the helpful answer, I ll look at the invoices and try add module to halve the price using invoices.  the good news about the requirement for my module, is that I don't need to automate the other half of the payment. so I just need to send half of the total to payment modules, and indicate to admin that user paid half . would overriding an invoice class make payment modules get the half price? or do you suggest another way.   thanks!

Comment: I would suggest observing the event `sales_order_invoice_register` which I believe is when an invoice's totals are calculated. Or perhaps you can find another event sometime during the `prepareInvoice()` function.

Comment: A cursory check reveals that invoices have their own way of calculating totals, see the Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml for "order_invoice" section. You could override one of those (probably subtotal) to control how it sums the ordered items.

Comment: I tried to insert code to change the amount of grand total in invoices, but it doesn't seem this is what payment modules are getting the total from.  I tested on paypal express checkout and what I noticed paypal gets the total from checkout/session get quote.   what did you do for your own module? thanks!

Comment: Did you find a best solution? I have the similar problem. Please describe what I need to do?